# SQL Server Stored Procedure is not raising error in my program

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTest]
@Pozitii varchar(max),
@NrZile int

AS   
set @Pozitii = SUBSTRING(@Pozitii,0,LEn(@Pozitii))

CREATE TABLE #Pozitii (part varchar(20) null)



INSERT INTO #Pozitii(part) 
SELECT part
FROM dbo.SDF_SplitString(@Pozitii,',')


if exists (SELECT * FROM #Pozitii)
 RAISERROR('asdf',16,-1)  
else     RAISERROR('else',16,-1)
```

So runing this SP in SQL like this

```
exec [spTest] '11,12,13,',1
```

Returns:

```
(3 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spTest, Line 27
asdf
```

Now if I run my procedure in delphi ( using an ADO object)

```
procedure TframePlanificatorPozitieComanda.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin


  try
    with dm.spTest do
    begin
      Close;
      Parameters.ParambyName('@Pozitii').Value := '11,12,13,';
      Parameters.ParambyName('@NrZile').Value := 1;
      ExecProc;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;

  end;
end;
```

This code is not raising any errors?Any ideas why?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: We would need to see your string splitter to be able to help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving ADO errors using Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457032/retrieving-ado-errors-using-delphi)

Comment: @JerryDodge it's SQL Server 2014. Anyways tomorrow i'll try the suggestions from the answer and come back with an answer. Thank you for the asnwers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

to your stored procedure?  I think the exception is in a second resultset and is getting hidden by the first select result count.

Comment: Good point, +1.  In fact SS Management Studio 2014's template for a new Stored Proc contains a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

The error is raising in `sql-server`.. but in `delphi` is not .. because there the procedure is already executed.. 
But in Delphi you can check if the procedure is run successfully or not regards what the result of the procedure (some of procedures have no output parameters).
In `delphi` please check your `adostoredprocedure.parameters[0]` like:

```
showmessage(vartostr(self.ADOStoredProc1.Parameters[0].Value))
```

.

```
if the result <> 0 that means error.
```

Comment: "because there the procedure is already executed"  Sorry, I don't think this is right.  The error should be picked up by the Ado/MDAC layer on the client and be returned to the Delphi app as a raised exception, although, of course, the Delphi app can be coded to suppress the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Server 2014, I don't get the behaviour you describe.

I have a stored proc on the server defined as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spRaiseError(@AnError int) 
AS
BEGIN
  declare @Msg Char(20)
  if @AnError > 0 
    begin
      Select @Msg = 'MyError ' + convert(Char(8), @AnError)
      RaisError(@Msg, 16, -1)
    end
  else
    select 1
END
```

I have a minimalist D7 Ado project with a TAdoConnection, TAdoQuery, TDataSource and TDBGrid connected up as you'd expect, a TEdit and a TButton.

Using this code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : String;
  ErrorCount : Integer;
begin
  S := 'exec spRaiseError ' + Edit1.Text;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := S;
  try
    AdoQuery1.Open;
  except
  end;

  ErrorCount := AdoConnection1.Errors.Count;
  Caption := IntToStr(ErrorCount);

end;
```

, if the number in Edit1 is > 0 I get only the error number on the form's caption, whereas if it contains 0 I see the value 1 in the DBGrid.

Btw, with "Stop on language exceptions" checked in the D7 debugger settings, without the try/except around AdoQuery1.Open, the debugger sees and catches the exception from the server.

Anyway, the take-home message from this answer is that you can use the TAdoConnection's Errors collection to detect whether there was an error and, if there was, you can get more information from it.  See the Delphi OLH amd MS Ado documentation for more info about the Errors collection of TAdoConnection and other Ado-based Delphi classes.